# Protobuf input validation and model translation

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'm at a company where we're currently using protobuf3 (with scalapb in my case) for a lot of our internal communication. This version of protobuf does away with the `optional` and `required` labels from previous versions due to the 'required is forever' argument. I can understand the argument from a protocol point of view, however this leaves at least us with a serialized result that is further away from our actual domain model when all nested messages are wrapped in `Option`s.

The simple, and ugly IMHO, solution is to just do `myProto.myField.getOrElse {throw Exception("bla"}` whenever a message field is accessed but I don't want a ton of `getOreElse`s sprinkled across my code base when the field must be present.

My question is, is there either:

1. A library that can help me translate protobuf messages into my domain model using my own case classes? Or
2. A (relatively) simple way of doing this myself in a generalized way without massive amounts of boilerplate? I took a stab at doing this myself with some reflection but I'm fairly new to Scala. It was non-obvious how to map a `scalapb.descriptors.FieldDescriptor` to an actual value of the correct type.

Thanks

Comment: In ScalaPB>=0.7, you can annotate a field with no_box=true which would prevent the `Option[]` box. This is a new feature that is not yet documented. You can see how it is used in the tests: https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/commit/92bb35f5cd4ab3c8ca4a4792f97f99c5ef793caf

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw that but unfortunately 0.7.0 doesn't have a stable release and so isn't an option for my team to use at the moment.